# Loading screen after submitting form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I've added this script.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#submit-button').click(function() { 
            $.blockUI({ css: { 
                border: 'none', 
                padding: '15px', 
                backgroundColor: '#000', 
                '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
                '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
                opacity: .5, 
                color: '#fff' 
            } }); 

            setTimeout($.unblockUI, 8000); 
        }); 
    }); 

</script>
```

And here is my input type submit.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="AM I ELIGIBLE?" id="submit-button" >
```

Now, the problem is, the loading screen also runs once I click the submit button, even if I don't have set inputs for the other input types (first name, phone number, email). :(

I want it to run once the validation of the form is okay.

I'm using jquery.blockUI.js

Thank you guys! :)

Here's my NEW code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $('#submit-button').click(function() { 


            //First set your var for the fields you want. the $() is the id of the field in your html 
                var firstName = $("#first-name").text();
                var lastName = $("#last-name").text();
                if(firstName != "")//&&(lastName != ""))
                {

                $.blockUI({ css: { 
                    border: 'none', 
                    padding: '15px', 
                    backgroundColor: '#000', 
                    '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
                    '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
                    opacity: .5, 
                    color: '#fff' 
                } }); 

                setTimeout($.unblockUI, 8000); 

                }
                // else{
                // // in here you'll do what ever you wanted to for instance.

                // alert("Please make sure all fields are filled out");
                // }

            });         
        }); 

        </script>
```

---

*---*

Now, I have a slider..

```
<p class="slider1">Your approximate total debt: 
  <output name="slider_output1" id="slider_output1" for="form_slider1">0</output><br>                                                   
  <input type="range" class="form_slider1" name="form_slider1" id="form_slider1"
   value="0" min="0" max="60000" step="100" 
   oninput="slider_output1.value=form_slider1.value" 
   onchange="slider_output1.value=value"/>  

</p>
```

I need to add this on the condition statement, so that the form won't go through if its value is "0".

I tried using this..

```
var slider1 = $("#form_slider1").val();
```

Then,
if(firstName != "" && lastName != "" && email != "" && phone != "" && doorNumber != "" && postcode != "" && (phoneLength.length > 9 || phoneLength.length < 12)) && slider1 > 0 )

But, I think it's disregarding that slider1>0, the loading screen is not showing either.

Let me know if this is not clear. :(

Comment: Ad an `if` statement inside click function, to check whether the input fields are with information!

Comment: It does work, it's not showing the loading screen now (when the input fields are empty). But the loading screen is not showing too, even if all the inputs are not empty anymore. :(

Comment: change type of the input from `type="submit"` to `type="button"` and submit the form inside your `.click()` function

Comment: Thanks guys for your help! Appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your on the right path, what you need to do first is check those fields.

```
           <script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#submit-button').click(function() {
//First set your var for the fields you want. the $() is the id of the field in your html 
var firstName = $("#FirstName").text();
if(firstName != "")
{
            $.blockUI({ css: { 
                border: 'none', 
                padding: '15px', 
                backgroundColor: '#000', 
                '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
                '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
                opacity: .5, 
                color: '#fff' 
            } }); 
 setTimeout($.unblockUI, 8000);
}else{
// in here you'll do what ever you wanted to for instance.

alert("Please make sure all fields are filled out");
}

        }); 
    }); 

</script>
```

Try this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#submit-button').click(function() { 


        //First set your var for the fields you want. the $() is the id of the field in your html 
            var firstName = $("#first-name").text().trim();
            var lastName = $("#last-name").text().trim();
           //Also use alert to make sure the field are really being filled out
            alert(firstName + " " + lastName);

            if(firstName == "" && lastName == "")
            {
             // // in here you'll do what ever you wanted to for instance.
              alert("Please make sure all fields are filled out");
            }
            else{

              $.blockUI({ css: { 
                border: 'none', 
                padding: '15px', 
                backgroundColor: '#000', 
                '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
                '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
                opacity: .5, 
                color: '#fff' 
            } }); 

            setTimeout($.unblockUI, 8000); 

           }

        });         
    }); 

    </script>
```

Comment: It does work, it's not showing the loading screen now (when the input fields are empty). But the loading screen is not showing too, even if all the inputs are not empty anymore. :(

Comment: Do you want it to show the loading even if the fields are empty? Also can you paste your new code so I can see it?

Comment: I just added the new code to my first post. What I mean is, even after all the fields have values, the loading screen is not showing after hitting the submit button.

Comment: I added to what you said above in my old post, try that

Comment: Please show me your html, it looks like your firstName and lastName are not being used properly. Actually try one more thing and Im sure this will help. change these $("#first-name").text().trim(); $("#last-name").text().trim(); to these $("#first-name").val().trim(); $("#last-name").val().trim();

Comment: One more thing. :(
I added the new problem on my first post.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I changed the .text() to a .val(). I also noticed on your site, when you hit f12 you have two errors you need to handle.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#submit-button').click(function() { 


    //First set your var for the fields you want. the $() is the id of the field in your html 
        var firstName = $("#first-name").val().trim();
        var lastName = $("#last-name").val().trim();
       //Also use alert to make sure the field are really being filled out
        alert(firstName + " " + lastName);

        if(firstName == "" && lastName == "")
        {
         // // in here you'll do what ever you wanted to for instance.
          alert("Please make sure all fields are filled out");
        }
        else{

          $.blockUI({ css: { 
            border: 'none', 
            padding: '15px', 
            backgroundColor: '#000', 
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
            opacity: .5, 
            color: '#fff' 
        } }); 

        setTimeout($.unblockUI, 8000); 

       }

    });         
}); 

</script>
```

Comment: One more thing. :(
I added the new problem on my first post.

Comment: Have you done an alert(slider1); to see if it is bringing back a value?

Comment: Use this to bring back the actual value of your slider $("#form_slider1").rangeinput(); Also I reccomend not using the same name for class and id.